# Show Text In A DIV On Blur Of Form Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been searching this for over 5 hours now with no help lol.

I want to have a form field (text) that someone can type into. Either as they type or after the blur of the field I want that text to show in a div on the screen. Maybe this is not possible.

Here is the last piece of code I tried and of course it does not work.

```
 <p>Headline Text:<br />
 <input type="text" name="headline" value="$headline" onChange="document.getElementById('headline2').value=this.value" /></p>
 <br />
 <div id="headline2"></div>
```

In that code, anything typed into `headline` would appear in the `<div id="headline2"></div>` on blur.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not far!!!
A `<div>` doesn't have a value... But has inner HTML. ;)

Here it is on change:

```html
    <p>Headline Text:<br />
      <input type="text" name="headline" value="$headline" onChange="document.getElementById('headline2').innerHTML=this.value" /></p>
    <br />
    <div id="headline2"></div>
```

And on keyup:

```html
    <p>Headline Text:<br />
      <input type="text" name="headline" value="$headline" onKeyup="document.getElementById('headline2').innerHTML=this.value" /></p>
    <br />
    <div id="headline2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var target = document.querySelector('div')

input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  target.innerHTML = input.value
})
```

I recommend keeping your scripts separate from the markup, but if you so choose...

```
<input onblur="document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = this.value">
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Form inputs have a value property, container elements such as divs have innerHTML. Try this instead:

```
<p>Headline Text:<br />
<input type="text" name="headline" value="$headline" 
onChange="document.getElementById('headline2').innerHTML=this.value" />
</p>
<br />
<div id="headline2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible, and you were very close with your attempt. The problem is that a `<div>` element doesn't have a `value`, only `innerHTML`. Also, you're probably looking for `onblur` instead of `onChange`:

```html
<p>Headline Text:<br />
  <input type="text" name="headline" value="$headline" onblur="document.getElementById('headline2').innerHTML = this.value" /></p>
<br />
<div id="headline2"></div>
```

Just remember that with `onblur`, you have to actually click outside of the element for the changes to show. If you want it to change whenever the user types something, you're looking for `onkeyup` instead.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="text" onkeyup="getTextVal()">
<div id="showtext"></div>
<script>
function getTextVal(){
    var val = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var showText = document.getElementById('showtext');
  showText.innerText = val;
}
</script>
```

See in jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/PenAndPapers/7qp6g5e2/)